# Does repeatedly zeroing vector dimensions always produce a linearly independent set?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have some vector with arbitrary values a,b,c,d.
\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \\ d\end{bmatrix}

If I were to create the following matrix in which each subsequent value were zeroed out, then would it be guaranteed to be linearly independent?

\begin{bmatrix}a & a & a & a \\ b & b & b & 0 \\ c & c & 0 & 0  
\\ d & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}

Also, what if we do a similar construction to the one above, but by rotating the vectors and zeroing one dimension, will it be linearly independent?

\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & d \\ b & c & d & 0 \\ c & d & 0 & 0  
\\ d & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}

I can prove the first one is linearly independent by column reduction. The second appears to be independent as well but I can't explain why.

So in general, does iteratively zeroing dimensions of a vector always lead to a linearly independent set? If so, why?

Comment: Certainly not.  If $a,b,c,d$ are arbitrary, then let them all be $0$, for instance.

Comment: Indeed, if _any_ of the four variables is $0$, neither matrix has full rank.

Comment: @amd doesn’t the second matrix have full rank if $(a,b,c,d) = (0,0,0,1)$?

Comment: @Joppy Yes. Overlooked that case.